# Run build after every commit to git repository at buildbot

Tags: buildbot

I'd like to run build after every commit to git repository. I've set-upped [GitPoller](http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/latest/GitPoller.html), which monitors my git repository on new commits and informs me about it, but I couldn't find how to do some action on this event. Maybe I have to use other [buildbot](http://buildbot.net/) functionality to do it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

The [`GitPoller`](http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/current/GitPoller.html) generates "change" events automatically. What you need is a [`Scheduler`](http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/current/Schedulers.html) to watch for those change events and kick off builds for them.